# Need help in sql query of Time Management system

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables 1 is EMployeeMaster and another is Attendance

```
***EmployeeMaster***

EmployeeId    EmployeeName   DepartmentId
1             ABC            1
2             XYZ            2
3             PQR            2
4             WXY            1
```

Now i have another table Attendance

```
***Attendance***

AttendanceId EmployeeId      Date                  InTime       OutTime
1            1            2011-04-04 00:00:00    10:00 AM     6:30 PM
2            2            2011-04-04 00:00:00    09:45 AM     7:10 PM
```

Once employee comes in office and put his finger on device his entry will be go to Attendance table with InTime ,EMployeeId and Date.

So the employee who is not come into office ,his entry will not exist in the Attendance table.

Now i want to generate daily report..It should show attendance of all the employee of company along with their Intime/outTime by date.
All the employees who are absent they also should be displayed in this report.

So i want :

```
EmployeeId    EMployeeName   DepartmentId  Date                 InTime    OutTime
1             ABC            1             2011-04-04 00:00:00  10:00 AM  6:30 PM
2             XYZ            2             2011-04-04 00:00:00  09:45 AM  7:10 PM
3             PQR            2             NULL/-               NULL/-    NULL/-
4             WXY            1             NULL/-               NULL/-    NULL/-
```

Can you tell me what should be query???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a left outer join.

```
declare @E table (EmployeeId int,    EmployeeName varchar(50),   DepartmentId int)
declare @A table (AttendanceId int, EmployeeId int, [Date] date, InTime time, OutTime time)

insert into @E values
(1,             'ABC',            1),
(2,             'XYZ',            2),
(3,             'PQR',            2),
(4,             'WXY',            1)

insert into @A values
(1,            1,            '2011-04-04 00:00:00',    '10:00 AM',     '6:30 PM'),
(2,            2,            '2011-04-04 00:00:00',    '09:45 AM',     '7:10 PM')

select
  E.EmployeeId,
  E.EmployeeName,
  E.DepartmentId,
  A.[Date],
  A.InTime,
  A.OutTime
from @E as E
  left outer join @A as A
    on E.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId and
       A.[Date] = '2011-04-04 00:00:00'
```

Result

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName                                       DepartmentId Date       InTime           OutTime
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------ ---------- ---------------- ----------------
1           ABC                                                1            2011-04-04 10:00:00.0000000 18:30:00.0000000
2           XYZ                                                2            2011-04-04 09:45:00.0000000 19:10:00.0000000
3           PQR                                                2            NULL       NULL             NULL
4           WXY                                                1            NULL       NULL             NULL
```

**Edit 1**

If you need to do this for one month I would use some kind of number table or calendar table. Here I have used a cte to build the calendar using @FromDate and @ToDate

```
declare @E table (EmployeeId int, EmployeeName varchar(15), DepartmentId int)
declare @A table (AttendanceId int, EmployeeId int, [Date] date, InTime time, OutTime time)

insert into @E values
(1, 'ABC', 1),
(2, 'XYZ', 2),
(3, 'PQR', 2),
(4, 'WXY', 1)

insert into @A values
(1, 1, '2011-04-02', '04:00 AM', '4:30 PM'),
(2, 2, '2011-04-02', '05:00 AM', '5:30 PM'),
(3, 1, '2011-04-03', '06:00 AM', '6:30 PM'),
(4, 2, '2011-04-03', '07:00 AM', '7:30 PM'),
(5, 1, '2011-04-04', '08:00 AM', '8:30 PM'),
(6, 2, '2011-04-05', '09:00 AM', '9:10 PM')

-- Set FromDate to first day of month
declare @FromDate date = '20110401'
-- Set ToDate to last day of month
declare @ToDate date = '20110405'

-- Create cte with all dates between FromDate and ToDate
;with cteCal as 
(
  select @FromDate as [Date]
  union all
  select dateadd(d, 1, [Date]) as [Date]
  from cteCal
  where [Date] < @ToDate
)
select
  E.EmployeeId,
  E.EmployeeName,
  E.DepartmentId,
  C.[Date],
  A.InTime,
  A.OutTime
from cteCal as C
  cross join @E as E
  left outer join @A as A
    on E.EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId and
       C.[Date] = A.[Date]
order by C.[Date], E.EmployeeName 
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: @Kishan - Not in where clause, in join. Updated answer.

Comment: I am having 1 issue..i hope you can help me...in current scenario when i will get monthly report...i will not come to know that on which date who is absent...So Is der any way i can achieve this...

Comment: @Kishan - updated answer. This probably should have been in another question so you could get more suggestions on how to do this than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Should look like this:

```
select 
  EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName,
  DepartmentId,
  Date,
  InTime,
  OutTime
from EmployeeMaster em
left join Attendance a on em.EmployeeId=a.EmployeeId and Date='2011-04-04 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Not getting employees who are absent ..SO EmployeeId-3 & 4 are not getting in result....

Comment: Ok .. you should get them now

Answer (score 0):

```
select E.EmloyeeId, EmployeeName, DepartmentId, Date, InTime, OutTime
from   EmployeeMaster as e
       LEFT JOIN Attendance as a ON a.EmloyeeId = e.EmloyeeId
```

Comment: See this works...but when i pass perticular date i am not getting employees who are absent...

`select E.EmployeeId, EmployeeName, DepartmentId, Date, InTime, OutTime
from   EmployeeMaster as e
       LEFT JOIN Attendance as a ON a.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId where a.Date='2011-04-04'`